# JQuery Sortable + Rails - Updating an External Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-sortable

I followed the Railscast episode on creating [Sortable Lists](http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists-revised?view=asciicast) and was successful in creating a sortable list that updates its model internally – In my application, projects have many steps (the steps are nested in projects), and I created a table with sortable steps that I can access when I open up the project_steps path.

What I'm now trying to do is update an external model (Images) from within the edit_project_steps path (steps have many images).  I'm not sure how to extend what is done in the Railscast to updating external models; now when I try to sort images within the edit_project_steps path, I get the error "**ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/projects/1/steps/2/edit")**"

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

Here's what I have so far:

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :projects do
    resources :steps do
        collection {post :sort}
      end
      match "steps/:id" => "steps#number", :as => :number
  end

  resources :images do
     collection {post :sort}
   end
```

**images.rb**

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
   # Sorts images
  def sort
    render nothing: true
  end

end
```

**steps/edit.html.erb**

```
<div class="imageGallery span8">
    <p style="margin: 5px 0px;"><b>Step Images</b> - Click and drag to rearrange</p>
      <div class = "wrapper">
        <div class="scrolls">
          <div class="imageDiv" id="stepImages" data-update-url="<%= sort_images_url %>">
            <div class="images">
              <%= render :partial => 'images/image', :collection => @step.images.all %>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

<% #drag images %>
<script>
$(".imageDiv .images").sortable({
  cursor: "move",
  axis: 'x', 
  update: function(){
    $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'));
        }
  }).disableSelection();
</script>
```

**rake routes**

```
            sort_project_steps POST       /projects/:project_id/steps/sort(.:format)     steps#sort
                 project_steps GET        /projects/:project_id/steps(.:format)          steps#index
                               POST       /projects/:project_id/steps(.:format)          steps#create
              new_project_step GET        /projects/:project_id/steps/new(.:format)      steps#new
             edit_project_step GET        /projects/:project_id/steps/:id/edit(.:format) steps#edit
                  project_step GET        /projects/:project_id/steps/:id(.:format)      steps#show
                               PUT        /projects/:project_id/steps/:id(.:format)      steps#update
                               DELETE     /projects/:project_id/steps/:id(.:format)      steps#destroy
                project_number            /projects/:project_id/steps/:id(.:format)      steps#number
                      projects GET        /projects(.:format)                            projects#index
                               POST       /projects(.:format)                            projects#create
                   new_project GET        /projects/new(.:format)                        projects#new
                  edit_project GET        /projects/:id/edit(.:format)                   projects#edit
                       project GET        /projects/:id(.:format)                        projects#show
                               PUT        /projects/:id(.:format)                        projects#update
                               DELETE     /projects/:id(.:format)                        projects#destroy
                   sort_images POST       /images/sort(.:format)                         images#sort
                        images GET        /images(.:format)                              images#index
                               POST       /images(.:format)                              images#create
                     new_image GET        /images/new(.:format)                          images#new
                    edit_image GET        /images/:id/edit(.:format)                     images#edit
                         image GET        /images/:id(.:format)                          images#show
                               PUT        /images/:id(.:format)                          images#update
                               DELETE     /images/:id(.:format)                          images#destroy
                          root            /                                              projects#index
```

Here's an image of what I'm trying to sort on the page:

[image: Images I'm trying to sort within the edit_project_step path]

Comment: from your error, it looks like it is posting to `/projects/1/steps/2/edit` instead of `sort_images_path` which is weird. can you try changing the url in your ajax to `$('.imageDiv').data('update-url')`. also make sure that you have only one `.imageDiv`

Comment: interesting.  when I change $(this).data('update-url') to $('imageDiv').data('update-url') as you suggested, the error goes away.  however, it doesn't return any parameters; it should return the order of the images on the page.  This is what I get in my console:
Started POST "/images/sort" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-08 23:21:35 -0500
Processing by ImagesController#sort as */*
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a series of issues...here is my final code for those that are interested:

**images.rb**

```
  def sort
    params[:image].each_with_index do |id, index|
      Image.update_all({position: index+1}, {id: id})
    end
    render nothing: true
  end
```

**steps/edit.html.erb**

```
<div class="imageGallery span8">
    <p style="margin: 5px 0px;"><b>Step Images</b> - Click and drag to rearrange</p>
    <div class = "wrapper">
      <div class="scrolls">
        <div id="images" data-update-url="<%= sort_images_url %>">
          <% @step.images.order("position").each do |image| %>
            <%=content_tag_for(:div, image) do %>
              <%= render :partial => 'images/image', :locals => {:image=> image} %>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<% #drag images %>
<script>
$("#images").sortable({
  cursor: "move",
  axis: 'x', 
  update: function(){
    $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'));
  }
  }).disableSelection();
</script>
```